# Issue facing in isKindOfClass in iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, ios10

Recently I have upgraded **XCode8** I am facing issue in `isKindOfClass` method this code is working till to `iOS9` but in `iOS10` suddenly `[items isKindOfClass: [NSMutableArray class]]` compiler not going in for loop condition may I know what is the reason?

`NSMutableArray` is child class of `NSArray` so when I am changing to `[NSArray class]` then it works fine so I am confuse why this change affect to `NSMutableArray` class which is child class of `NSArray` ?

```
     NSMutableArray *items = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"]; // Here i am taking response in NSMutableArray

     if ([items isKindOfClass: [NSMutableArray class]] && items != nil) // not working  {
         for (NSMutableDictionary *item in items)
         {
           // Rest of Code
         }
     }
```

This code works for me I m confuse the above code working until `iOS9` when I change this below code then after working in `iOS10`:

```
     NSMutableArray *items = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"];

     if ([items isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]] && items != nil) // Changed to NSArray  {
         for (NSMutableDictionary *item in items)
         {
           // Rest of Code
         }
     }
```

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON?  Are you setting the option for mutable containers?  Have you set a breakpoint and checked with a debugger, what `items` actually is?  All the evidence points to it being an `NSArray` rather than an `NSMutableArray`

Comment: @Paulw11 Yesi have checked all the things i have checked with debuger items has a items and this 1st block of code working till to iOS9 and i have checked with debugger when i changed NSMutableArray to NSArray then it will working fine and this happened only in iOS10

Comment: So, what is the class of `items` shown in the debugger?

Comment: it will showing `NSArray` class but NSMutableArray is child class of NSArray then why that is not working

Comment: So, there is your answer. It is an NSArray.  The problem isn't with `isKindOfClass` it is with how you are creating your objects.  There is an option you can pass to `NSJSONSerializer` if you want mutable containers.  By default you get immutable containers.

Comment: may i know why it is working in iOS9 ?

Comment: `isKindOfClass` will match superclasses, but not subclasses.  So if x is an `NSMutableArray` then both `[x isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]]` and `[x isKindOfClass: [NSMutableArray class]]` will return true.  But if x is an `NSArray` then only the first will be true, since a superclass instance isn't a subclass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123494/discussion-between-paulw11-and-mayank-patel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, it seems that you actually have an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`, so `isKindOfClass` is working correctly.  AFN will give immutable containers unless you specify otherwise, and this shouldn't be any different on iOS 10, so I am not sure why it was working previously.

Rather than testing for a mutable array, it is probably simpler to create a mutable copy of whatever is there, this way you don't have to try and handle the "failure" condition gracefully:

```
NSArray *items = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"];
if (items != nil) {
     NSMutableArray *mutableItems = [items mutableCopy];
     for (NSMutableDictionary *item in mutableItems)
     {
       // Rest of Code
     }
 }
```

Beware, unless you have specified the option to AFN to provide mutable containers, the dictionaries inside your `items` array will be `NSDictionary` not `NSMutableDictionary`, so you may need to make mutable copies of them.

Of course, if you aren't mutating the array or the dictionary, then you can just u `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` regardless of whether you have a mutable or immutable object.